# How to rename duplicated layers in QGIS3?

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-3

I duplicated a layer ("Buildings") in QGIS 3.4.4 and with the Query Builder under Source I selected to just display schools. Subsequently I renamed this layer "Schools" by rightclicking on the layer, choosing Rename Layer.

The new name of the layer appears but once I tick the box to toggle visibility it jumps back to its previous name ("Buildings"). I'm also unable to rename the layer under Source (the 'displayed as' field is greyed out), see screenshot below.

How can I rename this layer permanently?

[image]

**Edit 21-02-2019**: I found that in other projects the layer could be simply renamed or saved with a different name just as was suggested in the answers below. I have not been able to do it with the project I had worked on and suspect a bug of some sort with the imported layers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Select by expression` on the original layer (Building layer) to select the schools and then `right-click the building layer -> Export -> Save Selected Features As` and give the new feature a new name, Schools for example. The new schools layer will added to the canvas with only school features inside.

Comment: I have tried this and I didn't work with this project. I suspect a bug of some sort within the imported layers because in another project it worked this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

right click, open the attribute table, go into edit mode, delete all layers but the schools. Then right click again, save as... give it the name schools

Comment: This worked for me in another project but not this one. I think there might be a bug in an imported layer. Thank you.